# pyinstaller - C runtime DLL - crash of the app

Tags: c++, python, dll, pyinstaller

When I tried to build my app with py2exe, the executable chrashed on some PCs due to missing Microsoft DLL (PCs without installed Microsoft Visual C++ 200X Redistributable). This advice didn't solve the problem: http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial#Step52

Therefore I tried pyinstaller, which generates all required dlls + manifests. On the same PCs I don't face the problem with missing DLL, but executable crashes anyway without any reasonable message or creating log file.

How to solve the problem? It is even possible to build executable indepent on DLLs installed manually by user? As I'd like to create a protable application from my python script.

Comment: What was the error message reported when the exe from pyinstaller ran?

Comment: According error signature it is: "AppName: nam.exe  AppVer: 0.0.0.0  ModName: pygame.font.pyd". Which doesn't make a sense to me.

Comment: Hmm, this may be problem of missing fonts on the concrete PC..

Comment: Yes, it is problem of missing fonts. But it is strange, that any log file wasn't generated.